# How to mock angular translate filter in unit tests for directives

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-translate, angular-filters

In my directive templates, I need to use the angular translate filter as such:

```
    <label for="data-source-btn">
      <span id="data-source-btn-span"></span>
      {{'Data Source' | translate}}
    </label>
```

Then in my unit test for this directive, I get the error:

> Unknown provider: translateFilterProvider <- translateFilter

I've tried injecting `$filter` and getting `$translate` by `$translate = $filter('translate');` which doesn't solve the problem - this is really for testing the filter

I can inject the module `pascalprecht.translate`, but that is heavy handed. How do I best mock the filter?

Answer (score 51):

Below is a simple example of how you can mock the filter.

```
var mockTranslateFilter;

beforeEach(function() {
  module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('translateFilter', mockTranslateFilter);
  });

  mockTranslateFilter = function(value) {
    return value;
  };
});
```

Comment: Can I actually mock a translation here?

Comment: When using this I still get a `Failed to instantiate module app.translate due to: Unknown provider: $translateProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. But of course you should set mockTraslateFilter value to function bewfore you will use it in another funciton.

```
var mockTranslateFilter;

beforeEach(function() {
  mockTranslateFilter = function(value) {
    return value;
  };
  module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('translateFilter', mockTranslateFilter);
  });
});
```

even shorter, if you use ES6:

```
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(progressBarComponent, ($provide) =>      {
        $provide.value('translateFilter', (v) => v);
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the ES6 way:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myModule'), ($provide) => {
    $provide.value('$translate', t => ({ then: cb => cb(t) }));
}));
```

This does not mock the $translate.instant method. For this you could assign the function to a variable and then assign the angular.identity method to the `instant`property.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution which worked for me is to add this line in your test file:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('pascalprecht.translate'));
```