# How to mock custom filter in Angular/Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a custom filter I created. per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397515/how-to-mock-angular-translate-filter-in-unit-tests-for-directives) I created the following in my Jasmine...

```
beforeEach(module("workOrderManagerApp"));
var mockSearchFilter = function(text, tails, fillTailList) {
    return null;
};
beforeEach(function() {
    module(function($provide) {
        $provide.value('searchItems', mockSearchFilter);
    });
});
```

But when I run this it still runs the non-mock filter. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add `Filter` to the end of your filter name so that `searchItems` would be `searchItemsFilter`. It isn't intuitive, you just have to know about this. Angular stores filters just like services, but adds `Filter` to the end of the name you pass in.

You would inject a filter like this:

```
.controller('MyController', [
  'searchItemsFilter', 
  function(searchItems) {

  }
])
```

and so you would mock it with: `$provide.value('searchItemsFilter', mockSearchFilter);`